# UVmagic tab, where is it?

Tags: uv, interface

I can't find the tab in the tool shelf for uv magic. The right click menu shows up, but I can't see it as described in the tutorial.

Location    3D View > Sidebar > UV Manipulation.

Also does anyone know of a video tutorial in English?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I found it, I had to reinstall the addon. I didn't realise it comes as part of 2.79 so I downloaded it from the net. When I installed the download I got a duplicate warning, so I removed the folders mentioned in the warning. That really screwed it. So restored folders from waste basket, restart and there it is! the V magic tab below display tab.